# Autofac singleton from factory method

Tags: c#, autofac, easynetq

I'm pretty much looking for a port to Autofac that is implemented [here](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Wiring-up-EasyNetQ-with-TopShelf-and-Windsor) with Castle Windsor. The `IBus` is an interface provided by EasyNetQ library and I'd like to register a factory that would instantiate the IBus instance as a singleton. `BusBuilder.CreateMessageBus` is the factory method. Example in Castle Windsor:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IBus>()
             .UsingFactoryMethod(BusBuilder.CreateMessageBus)
             .LifestyleSingleton()
    );
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
container.Register(c => BusBuilder.CreateMessageBus())
         .As<IBus>()
         .SingleInstance();
```

or

```
container.RegisterInstance(BusBuilder.CreateMessageBus())
         .As<IBus>();
```

The second solution will create the `IBus` instance during Autofac configuration whereas the second solution will create it the first time an `IBus` is resolved by *Autofac*